# Rest service in Java runs from Tomcat server but not inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, properties, javabeans

I am unable to find another article that solves my problem but am happy to hear about one if you know the answer.

I have a RESTful service built in Java with Eclipse. It uses Spring and all of its bells and whistles.

After much work with configuration files, I am able to build the service into a war file, deploy it to my Tomcat webapps folder, and run it from standalone Tomcat. However, it still throws several errors on start when I try to start it from a service defined within Eclipse. The errors are the same errors that I was seeing before I got the config files correct for standalone Tomcat. The errors are about the inability to create the required beans because of references to properties that can't be found.

How did I get it running in Tomcat? I added a couple of .properties files to define properties needed by the beans that get launched at startup and then added a 'set CLASSPATH=...' line to the setenv.bat file in the Tomcat bin folder. This new line adds the properties files into the CLASSPATH. That seems to have fixed everything from standalone Tomcat.

So, my question is, "How do I make these same changes inside my Eclipse server?" I have added the properties folder with the property files under the config folder in Eclipse, just like it is in my native Tomcat folders, but I do not know how to modify the CLASSPATH string to specifically point to my .properties files (as I have done in the setenv.bat file for standalone Tomcat).

I think I understand the problem, but have no idea about the solution.

Thanks for listening.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not use any `*.sh/*.bat` files to startup Tomcat. In order to modify the way the server is started you have to open the configuration UI of the server by double-clicking on the server in the *Servers* view.

From there you will be able to modify the classpath of the system classloader through *"Open launch configuration"*.

Another important setting is *"Server path"* which tells Eclipse, the value of `$CATALINA_BASE`. You can modify it only after removing all modules and cleaning the server. It is useful to set it to an easily accessible directory: this way you can verify directly that Eclipse didn't mess up your application deployment (sometimes it *"forgets"* to copy some libraries).

The *"Configuration path"* setting tells Eclipse where to find the files (but not subdirectories) that will be copied into `$CATALINA_BASE/conf`.

**Remark**: if your application requires you to add libraries to the top classloader, there is probably a problem in your project. The *"missing"* libraries should be added to `WEB-INF/lib` of your application instead: look into the *"Deployment assembly"* of your Eclipse project configuration.